Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://accounts.google.com' from frame with URL 'about:srcdoc'
I am trying to work with Google Doc Api integration. In localhost, I successfully fetched the data from google doc. Then I just put the whole code inside an iframe. Now I am getting Access blocked: Authorization Error.
In my website "xyz.com", there is an iframe containing sandox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups allow-downloads". This iframe loads the code.
In the cloud console, I have set "Authorized JavaScript origins" to "xyz.com".
In the browser console, I am getting this error: Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://accounts.google.com' from frame with URL 'about:srcdoc'. The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed and is trying to navigate a popup, but is not the popup's opener and is not set to propagate sandboxing to popups.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Google Docs Viewer</title>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="buttonDiv" style="display: none">
      <button id="authorizeButton" style="display: none">Authorize</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script>
      const API_KEY = "<API_KEY>";
      const CLIENT_ID = "<CLIENT_ID>";

      const DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://docs.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"];
      const SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly";

      let tokenClient;
      let gapiInited = false;
      let gisInited = false;

      function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load("client", initializeGapiClient);
      }

      async function initializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      }

      function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES,
          callback: "", // defined later
        });
        gisInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      }

      function maybeEnableButtons() {
        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
          document.getElementById("buttonDiv").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("authorizeButton").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("authorizeButton").onclick = handleAuthClick;

          // Check if the user is already signed in
          if (gapi.client.getToken() !== null) {
            fetchDoc();
          }
        }
      }

      function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
          if (resp.error !== undefined) {
            throw resp;
          }
          document.getElementById("authorizeButton").innerText = "Refresh";
          await fetchDoc();
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "consent" });
        } else {
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({ prompt: "" });
        }
      }

      async function fetchDoc() {
        let response;
        try {
          // Replace with your Google Doc ID
          const docId = "13wp3h7-e-Dmo0olOwPHZ9y0Xn5ewnkTZBlzQsmTPFhQ";
          response = await gapi.client.docs.documents.get({
            documentId: docId,
          });
        } catch (err) {
          document.getElementById("content").innerText = err.message;
          return;
        }
        const doc = response.result;
        document.getElementById("content").innerText = JSON.stringify(
          doc,
          null,
          2
        );
      }
    </script>
    <script
      async
      defer
      src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="gapiLoaded()"
    ></script>
    <script
      async
      defer
      src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"
      onload="gisLoaded()"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>



This question is similar to: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
